# Select multiple columns from multiple tables where you a trying to display all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

The instructions are

> Create and execute a SELECT statement that outputs the order number, customer number, and the order date for all the records in the Orders relation.

I had

```sql
select onum, cnum, Odate
from orders
join customers
```

But I don't know how to select all records

Comment: What isn't working about your attempt? Why isn't it returning all the "records"? What is a record, and tables have rows and columns; record has no meaning.

Comment: Im trying to display the onum,cnum(foreign key) and Odate from the orders  table for all the data that i have inserted into that table but I don't know what condition I can use to display all of them

Comment: Showing sample data and expected results would help.

Answer (score 1):

1. `select onum,cnum,Odate from orders join customers using`  + some join key
2. `select * from orders where`  + condition for sales representative (e.g. their id)

You need to provide the table schema so that I can fill in the missing information

Comment: Im sorry that was included on accident. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The answer for number 2 is right thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer actually is

```
select odId, cnum, Odate
from orders
```